# How is this step reached in the sum?

Tags: polynomials, summation

I have the following equation from this paper:

https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/106948/Roy_Aggresive%20flight.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y
[image]

In this paper the author supposedly uses 104 to reach from 107 to 108. What I don't understand is how the external sum that has bounds from 0 to 2N was reached at. How was the external sum reached at?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could somehow fine-tune the limits of the summation more if you wanted, but the point is that you do not have to. And you end up with a nicer looking formula if you enlarge the limits slightly.

More concretely: already in (107), you can start the summation at $n=0$ since for $n<r$ there is a zero in the product $\prod_{m=0}^{r-1}(n-m)$, so you are just summing up zeros.

Then of course, by squaring the polynomial, the degree of the polynomial doubles. So instead of summing up to $N$, you have to sum up to $2N$. If you were even more lazy, you could consider all the summations from zero to infinity. If you adopt the convention that $p_i=0$ for every $i<0$, then everything would work fine again.